# How do I use cookies as the backing store for a base controller property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to store some user preferences in a cookie and have that cookie loaded in the base controller and serialized into a property on the base controller all derived controllers can use.

What I have currently only works with reading but not writing as updating sub-properties won't trigger the setter to update the cookie data.

```
public class UserPreferences
{
    string int PageSize {get; set;}
    string int ThemeId {get; set;}
}

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly CookieManager _cookieManager;

    public UserPreferences UserPreferences
    {
        get
        {
            var userPreferences = _cookieManager.GetUserPreferences();

            return userPreferences;
        }
        set 
        {
            _cookieManager.SetUserPreferences(value);
        }
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // This doesn't trigger the setter.
        UserPreferences.PageSize = 10; 
        
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using Session for user preferences. (if user disabled the cookies, then user preferences would be lost).

Comment: @iSR5 I'd prefer to avoid session. That's why I moved to using cookies.

Comment: can we use session database like Redis?

Comment: @TinyWang no distributed caching or external stores will be available in this scenario

Comment: but to be honest, I think a distributed caching or external stores is necessary for your scenario... sorry for can't offering any useful suggestion..